# Interaction risk ratio from logistic regression in marginaleffects package in R

Tags: r, emmeans, r-marginaleffects

I'm have a logistic regression model predicting interest (0=no interest, 1=interest) with randomised experimental condition (0=control, 1=experimental), sex, sex:condition interaction, and several other covariates included as predictors.

Using `marginaleffects` package in R, I need to work out two things:

1. Sex-specific risk ratio (RR) for the effect of the experimental condition on interest (marginalising over other covariates).
2. The interaction term (i.e., ratio of risk ratios: RR<sub>men</sub> / RR<sub>women</sub>) for how many times greater the RR was for men than women.

Here is the logistic regression model:

```
model <- glm(data=dt, formula=interest ~ condition*sex + other_covariates,
              family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

I have successfully completed objective (1) — calculating the sex-specific marginal risk ratios (RR<sub>men</sub> & RR<sub>women</sub>) — using the following:

```
marginaleffects::avg_comparisons(model, comparison="ratio",
                variables="condition",by="sex")
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to calculate (2) — the ratio of risk ratios (RR<sub>men</sub> / RR<sub>women</sub>) — alongside its associated confidence intervals.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If this is more straightforward to do using another package like `emmeans` I'm also happy to use that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hypothesis` argument to conduct (non)linear tests on any quantity generated by the `marginaleffects` package. See the very detailed tutorial here:

https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/hypothesis.html

You do not provide a minimal working example, so I can't provide a fully working solution, but your code could end up looking like this:

```r
avg_comparisons(model, 
   comparison="ratio",
   variables="condition",
   by="sex",
   hypothesis = "b1 / b2 = 1")
```

Note that I have only added the last argument, telling `marginaleffects` that we want to check if the ratio of the first estimate to the second is different from 1. When I say "first" estimate, I mean the first row in the output of the same command if you just remove the `hypothesis` argument.